# Как в Qt из GNU/Linux собирать статически слинкованные приложения на Windows. (не требующие библиотек Qt для запуска и работы)

Tags: c++, qt, компиляция, qtcreator, qmake

Пошагово и простым языком, если не трудно...

Comment: имхо, никак. Для статической линковки нужна статическая библиотека, а в qt, на сколько я знаю, используются динамические библиотеки. Да и зачем? Ведь преимущества динамической линковки очевидны...

Comment: ну а для того чтобы собирать на linux программы на qt под windows вам минимум нужны будут: кросс-компилятор, система сборки, qt под windows и wine (последнее не обязательно, но без него вы не сможете проверить вашу прогу)

Comment: Для начала придется приобрести коммерческую лицензию QT. Затем можете обратится в Qt Support Helpdesk.

Comment: Ассоциация: [Building a windows executable in qt on a Linux system](https://askubuntu.com/q/656219/535039)

Comment: @VTT не обязательно, можно открыть исходный код, тогда все будет удовлетворять требованиям GPL